# How can I convert multiple layers to separate smart objects in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I have several layers in a Photoshop document that I would like to convert to smart objects (I'm going to be doing a lot of resizing).  However, when I right click or use the menu command to do so, all the selected layers are flattened into one smart object.  Is there a way to batch convert several layers into their own smart objects?

I realize at this point it might be just easier to use InDesign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this directly in Photoshop.

You can use [scripts](https://forums.adobe.com/message/3471484#3471484) to do this through Bridge. You can convert files from Bridge to smart objects by dragging them into Photoshop. You will have to export the layers to files first though.

Comment: This is a good suggestion although I think the reason it's so difficult to batch create smart objects is so we're pushed to use a more appropriate program.  I ended up using InDesign for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Way too late to answer, but for anyone else who might end up here:
You can try this adobe plugin:

https://exchange.adobe.com/creativecloud.details.102929.layer-batch-processing-kit.html

Apart from this, I think Layrs Control 2 which used to be a free program was able to do it.